# STM32 Flash programming over SWD without a programmer

Tags: stm32

I am looking for a data sheet explaining the details of the programming algorithm for STM32 devices over the SWD port. I need to program a large panel of PCB all at the same time, and am finding hooking up 20 programmers to run in parallel a real pain.
My plan is to build a simple custom programmer that I can control directly over say an SPI interface. That way I can drive lots of these programmers at the same time easily on an in-circuit test machine. I have done similar things for a PIC.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't program many uCs using the same signal as SWD communicates both ways. You can program them one by one, or you will need many programmers to archive it.

Comment: I appreciate you can't connect connect one programmer to many SWD pins as they are bidirectional, I am asking for the serial commands needed to program the device without using a ST-Link programmer, The multiple USB connections is causing me the trouble, this is why I want to do it with SPI interface instead.

Comment: **over SWD** means by the debug interface. BTW you cant use the built in bootloader as well as it communicates both ways as well

Answer (score 0):

stm32 chips are arms on the inside. The debug interface is described here [ARM DEBUG v5.2](https://www.pjrc.com/tmp/ARM_debug.v5.2.pdf).

To program multiple chips at once you will need a multiplexer, or as you said, multiple programmers regardless of if you build these programmers yourself.

For an extra fee, ST provides a flashing service for their chips. It would make sense to write a boot-loader and have them flash that. Then you could use a bus of some kind to communicate with the boot-loader of each chip and flash all your chips in parallel. writing such a boot-loader shouldn't be too hard.

Another solution could be to use JTAG instead of SWD since JTAG is designed to have multiple taps. you would connect the TDO to the TDI of the next chip and create a super long tap chain of all your chips. You still would not be able to flash the chips in parallel, but at least you could do it with one debugger.

here's one more *outlandish* proposal: Connect all your stm32 devices in series. Then flash the first device with a fw that will connect to the next device and flash it with its own firmware before continuing to run the actual application ;). make sure you have some kind of check to see if re-flashing is necessary. i.e. you don't flash all your chips at power up every time...